# JavaFX - Large amount of Data in ScrollPane freezes UI

Tags: java, javafx

**What i need to do?**

I need to display a lot of Data.
1 GridPane exists of ~25 Labels. There need to be 100-500 of those GridPanes to be shown.

**How did i do it?**

I used a ScrollPane for it.
So there are many GridPanes in a VBox which is placed into a ScrollPane.
I generate the GridPanes in an extra Thread and just set the Content of the ScrollPane in the JavaFX-Thread.

Some of those Labels are modified Labels so they are copyable or Links.

**What happens?**

The UI freezes for some seconds bevor the data is displayed.

**Question1:** Is there some modification i can make to prevent the UI from freezing?
**Question2:** Are there other Components better suited to display such Data?

**ExampleCode:**

```java
package samples.longload;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Longload extends Application
{
    private final Button runButton = new Button("Run");
    private final Label label = new Label();
    final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    final VBox vb = new VBox();

    private final Service service = new Service()
    {
        @Override
        protected Task createTask()
        {
            return new Task<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception
                {
                    final List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                    {
                        final GridPane grid = defineGrid();
                        nodeList.add(grid);
                    }
                    vb.getChildren().addAll(nodeList);

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            sp.setContent(vb);
                        }
                    });

                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage)
    {
        final VBox layout = createLayout();

        final Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 1500, 1000);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        bindUIandService(stage);

        stage.show();
    }

    private void bindUIandService(final Stage stage)
    {
        label.textProperty()
             .bind(service.stateProperty().asString()
             );

        stage.getScene()
             .getRoot()
             .cursorProperty()
             .bind(
                   Bindings
                           .when(service.runningProperty())
                           .then(Cursor.WAIT)
                           .otherwise(Cursor.DEFAULT)
             );

        runButton
                 .disableProperty()
                 .bind(
                       service.runningProperty()
                 );

        runButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event)
            {
                service.restart();
            }
        });
    }

    private VBox createLayout()
    {
        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        sp.setPrefSize(300, 500);
        sp.setVmax(440);
        sp.setContent(new ProgressIndicator());
        layout.getChildren().setAll(runButton, label, sp);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        return layout;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private LinkedHashMap<Node, Node> createContentMap()
    {
        final LinkedHashMap<Node, Node> contentMap = new LinkedHashMap<Node, Node>();

        // ID-KONSEH
        contentMap.put(new Label("1"), new Label("1", null));
        // ID-DOKUMENT
        contentMap.put(new Label("2"), new Label("2"));
        // DISCRIMINATOR
        contentMap.put(new Label("3"), new Label("3"));
        // AKT
        contentMap.put(new Label("4"), new Label("4"));
        // FASSUNGSNR
        contentMap.put(new Label("5"), new Label("5"));
        // KORREKTURNR
        contentMap.put(new Label("6"), new Label("6"));
        // STATUS
        contentMap.put(new Label("7"), new Label("7"));
        // NEUZUGANG
        contentMap.put(new Label("8"), new Label("8"));
        // NEUZDAT
        contentMap.put(new Label("9"), new Label("9"));
        // APPDATVON
        contentMap.put(new Label("10"), new Label("10"));
        // APPDATBIS
        contentMap.put(new Label("11"), new Label("11"));
        // BEZUGVON
        contentMap.put(new Label("12"), new Label("12"));
        // BEZUGBIS
        contentMap.put(new Label("13"), new Label("13"));
        // INKRAFTVON
        contentMap.put(new Label("14"), new Label("14"));
        // INKRAFTBIS
        contentMap.put(new Label("15"), new Label("15"));
        // APPROBANT
        contentMap.put(new Label("16"), new Label("16"));
        // SACHBEARBEITER
        contentMap.put(new Label("17"), new Label("17"));
        // KURZTEXT
        contentMap.put(new Label("18"), new Label("18"));
        // PERSANMERKUNG
        contentMap.put(new Label("19"), new Label("19"));
        // LASTCHANGEDAT
        contentMap.put(new Label("20"), new Label("20"));
        // WIEDERVORLAGE_DATUM
        contentMap.put(new Label("21"), new Label("21"));
        // TEMP_GID
        contentMap.put(new Label("22"), new Label("22"));
        // DOK_MULTIFASSUNG
        contentMap.put(new Label("23"), new Label("23"));
        // ABGEFERTIGT_VON
        contentMap.put(new Label("24"), new Label("24"));
        // KORRIGIERT_VON
        contentMap.put(new Label("25"), new Label("25"));

        return contentMap;
    }

    public GridPane defineGrid()
    {
        final GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10)); // top, right, bottom, left
        grid.setHgap(10); // horizontaler Abstand
        grid.setVgap(10); // vertikaler Abstand
        final int columnWidthDescription = 150; // breite der Beschreibungs-Spalten
        final int columnWidthContent = 250; // breite der Inhalts-Spalten
        final ColumnConstraints columnDescription1 = new ColumnConstraints(columnWidthDescription, columnWidthDescription, columnWidthDescription);
        final ColumnConstraints columnContent1 = new ColumnConstraints(columnWidthContent, columnWidthContent, columnWidthContent);
        final ColumnConstraints columnDescription2 = new ColumnConstraints(columnWidthDescription, columnWidthDescription, columnWidthDescription);
        final ColumnConstraints columnContent2 = new ColumnConstraints(columnWidthContent, columnWidthContent, columnWidthContent);
        final ColumnConstraints columnDescription3 = new ColumnConstraints(columnWidthDescription, columnWidthDescription, columnWidthDescription);
        final ColumnConstraints columnContent3 = new ColumnConstraints(columnWidthContent, columnWidthContent, columnWidthContent);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnDescription1, columnContent1, columnDescription2, columnContent2, columnDescription3,
                                           columnContent3);

        final LinkedHashMap<Node, Node> contentMap = createContentMap();
        int column = 0;
        int row = 1;
        for (final Node desc : contentMap.keySet())
        {
            final Node content = contentMap.get(desc);
            if (row > contentMap.size() / 3)
            {
                column = column + 2;
                row = 1;
            }
            grid.add(desc, column, row);
            grid.add(content, column + 1, row);
            row++;
        }
        return grid;
    }
}
```

**This is how it should look like in the end:**
[image]

Comment: [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm)?

Comment: If `ListView` isn't suitable you may want to edit your question to include an image of how the data should be displayed. I'm having a hard time imagining how the end result should look like.

Comment: Edited the main-post and added an Image

Comment: As mentioned by @CeilingGecko you should think about to use a `ListView`. In addtion you can then show for example the first 50 items and, if the user scrolls to the end of the list, then add the next 50 items to the list.

Comment: ListView did it for me. Thanks.